# C# - How to get the Text Cursor on a Windows OS machine for a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, service

I'm trying to develop a Windows service that runs in the background and waits for a certain type of event (let's say, a USB drive insertion) and inserts a parameter into the active textbox on the system.

For example, let's say I'm trying to log into Facebook and I'm typing out my email. I want my service to automatically fill out the email field with the name of the USB pen I inserted, without any interaction from the user.

Is such a thing possible? At the moment, my service copies the text parameter into the Clipboard and displays a message saying it was updated.

Also, I'm using C# on Visual Studio Express 2013.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** I should clarify that my question is not only if this is possible, but how it can be done! :-)

Comment: almost certainly doable

Comment: A service does not seem a good fit for this, they are isolated from users & run in their own session. Your clipboard approach won't work as your service's clipboard is not the users clipboard - what if there were 2 active users? Who's clipboard would win the data?  If you want to do something per-user make software that runs when a user logs on.

Comment: Well, the clipboard approach is only a temporary solution. Is there any way to directly extract the data and send it to the active text box anywhere on the system?

Comment: Services by design run isolated from any logged on users.  If you really wanted to use a service you would create another desktop application that ran when a user logged on and have it use some form of IPC mechanism to talk to the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work around the issue by converting the obtained string to Windows keystrokes using the SendInput API.